# Is it possible to horizontally add a QTableWidget to a layout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.3

I have written a piece of code to print questions side by side with a score table. However when trying the present the table using a `QHBoxLayout` (if run) the table is not presented, but no error is shown. On the other hand, when using `QVBoxLayout`, it is shown when I run the code.
Is it possible that I could present the table side by side (horizontally) with the question/answer boxes? Would a splitter work as an alternative and, if so, how could I implement that in my code?

My code is as follows:

```
import sys, os, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
StudentNames = []
StudentScores = []

class StartTest(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, questions, parent=None):
        global StudentNames
        global StudentScores
        super(StartTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.stack = QtGui.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stack)
        StudentNames.append('Hamzah Akhtar')
        StudentNames.append('Bob Marley')
        StudentNames.append('John Meadows')
        StudentScores.append(int(0))
        StudentScores.append(int(0))
        StudentScores.append(int(0))
        for index, question in enumerate(questions):
            page = Question(question, self)
            page.submit.clicked[()].connect(
                lambda index=index: self.handleSubmit(index))
            self.stack.addWidget(page)
        self.answers = []

    def handleSubmit(self, index):
        page = self.stack.widget(index)
        answer = page.answer.text()
        # validate submitted answer...
        self.answers.append(answer)
        if index < self.stack.count() - 1:
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)

class Question(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, question, parent=None):
        global StudentNames
        global StudentScores
        super(Question, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.Table.setRowCount(3)
        self.Table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.Table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(StudentNames)
        self.Table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Scores'])
        self.question = QtGui.QLabel(question, self)
        self.answer = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.submit = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit', self)
        form = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        form.addRow(self.question, self.answer)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(form)
        layout.addWidget(self.submit)
        hlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlayout.addLayout(layout)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.Table)
        self.setLayout(hlayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User = ''
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    questions = [
        'What is 5+5?',
        'What is 45+10?',
        'What is 28+47?',
        'What is 22+13?',
        ]
    window = StartTest(questions)
    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a placeholder widget as the central widget. Then add a horizontal layout and add the widgets to that layout.

```
centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
self.scoreTable = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
self.scoreTable.setRowCount(len(StudentNames))
self.scoreTable.setColumnCount(1)
self.scoreTable.setVerticalHeaderLabels(StudentNames)
self.scoreTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Scores'])
for i, score in enumerate(StudentScores):
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(score))
    self.scoreTable.setItem(i, 0, item)

mainLayout.addWidget(self.stack)
mainLayout.addWidget(self.scoreTable)
```

Complete example: (tested with PySide but should work the same in pyqt)

```
import sys, os, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
StudentNames = []
StudentScores = []

class StartTest(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, questions, parent=None):
        global StudentNames
        global StudentScores
        super(StartTest, self).__init__(parent)

        self.stack = QtGui.QStackedWidget(self)
        StudentNames.append('Hamzah Akhtar')
        StudentNames.append('Bob Marley')
        StudentNames.append('John Meadows')
        StudentScores.append(int(0))
        StudentScores.append(int(0))
        StudentScores.append(int(0))
        for index, question in enumerate(questions):
            page = Question(question, self)
            page.submit.clicked[()].connect(
                lambda index=index: self.handleSubmit(index))
            self.stack.addWidget(page)
        self.answers = []

        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        self.scoreTable = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.scoreTable.setRowCount(len(StudentNames))
        self.scoreTable.setColumnCount(1)
        self.scoreTable.setVerticalHeaderLabels(StudentNames)
        self.scoreTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Scores'])
        for i, score in enumerate(StudentScores):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(score))
            self.scoreTable.setItem(i, 0, item)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.stack)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.scoreTable)

    def handleSubmit(self, index):
        page = self.stack.widget(index)
        answer = page.answer.text()
        # validate submitted answer...
        self.answers.append(answer)
        if index < self.stack.count() - 1:
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)

class Question(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, question, parent=None):
        super(Question, self).__init__(parent)
        self.question = QtGui.QLabel(question, self)
        self.answer = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.submit = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit', self)
        form = QtGui.QFormLayout(self)
        form.addRow(self.question, self.answer)
        form.addRow(self.submit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User = ''
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    questions = [
        'What is 5+5?',
        'What is 45+10?',
        'What is 28+47?',
        'What is 22+13?',
        ]
    window = StartTest(questions)
    window.show()
    # window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: How could i edit this to update the QTableWidget every time the submit button is clicked? I.e. Everytime the user clicks the submit button, i wanted the program to add 1 to the score. I know how to do that, but the QTableWidget does not refresh?

Comment: I uploaded the code in a new question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413244/how-would-i-refresh-the-qtablewidget-when-submit-is-clicked)